# does killing a process using java code several times(Internet explorer/chrome) crashes the system?

Tags: java, process

I am working on a small program in Java, where the written code  opens a URL in Mozilla/Chrome, waits for few seconds and kills it after few seconds. The process repeats for several URLS.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
String[] cmd = new String[3]; 
cmd[0] = "cmd.exe"; 
cmd[1] = "/C"; 
cmd[2] = "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe"; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Does killing an external process using java code crashes the browser or system? Will it affect the system?

Comment: What specifically is `killing` ?

Comment: shutting a process like we do from task manager. I use this code to kill all instances of chrome    String[] cmd = new String[3];
cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
cmd[1] = "/C" ;
cmd[2] = "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe" ;
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );

Comment: if you kill a chrome from task manager forcefully then when you open again Chrome will show you a nice message that will surely answer your question . Message: **He is Dead Jim**

Comment: yes it says 'chrome didnt shut down properly'..but im stil confused if i have a task of opening several urls and kill it(say a 50-100) ..kind of automate it, does it crashes chrome? does it crashes the system as well.please assist

Comment: If you kill Chrome there is nothing that could crash anymore. The system itself should be unaffected by killing a browser process.

Comment: "taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe" kills **all** processes with the name "chrome.exe"